# Morphism of R-algebras between R-adic algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, topological-groups

Let $R$ be a $f$-adic ring. Let $A$ and $B$ be $R$-adic algebras. I would like to show that any morphism of $R$-algebras between $A$ and $B$ is actually adic.

Comment: I don't know the terminology in this setting.  Are $R$-adic, $f$-adic, and adic all the same, or do you really mean to use a different term each time?

Comment: I think an $R$-adic algebra $A$ is just a $f$-adic ring such that you have an adic morphism $R \rightarrow A$.